# Implicit functions with defined $dy/dx$ at points where y is not locally a function of x.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The justification for implicit differentiation is a consequence of implicit function theorem, in that when given $F(x,y) =0 $, and differentiating y with respect to x, I am saying that y locally is a function of x in some neighborhood. That is, when I differentiate y implicitly I am making the assumption that y is a function of x.

For all of the examples I come up with, if you differentiate a implicitly and solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, at the points where y is not locally a function of x, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is undefined, but is this a direct consequence of the point not having a neighborhood where y is locally a function of x? Or are there examples where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is actually defined at such points (giving "fraudulent derivatives" based on the false assumption that y is a function of x locally near these points?)

Comment: The whole discussion raises the question of what $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is when $y$ is not a function of $x$.

Comment: It's probably not a coincidence that dy/dx is not defined at points where y is not a function of x, but this seems too convenient, which is why I wonder if there are examples where dy/dx is defined at (x,y) under the false assumption?

Comment: The fact that the derivative of the function $y(x)$ with respect to $x$ does not exist when there isn't a function $y$ that depends on $x$ does not appear to be a coincidence to me. More like a tautology. This raises the question on how you were thinking to "determine" that quantity, though.

Comment: Isn't it also possible that the derivative dy/dx can be defined under the false assumption that y is a function of x?

Comment: And how would that work?

Comment: Maybe I should ask my question in a different way, if I use implicit differentiation to solve for dy/dx at a given point (x,y), do I need to first show that y is indeed a function of x at that point to know that this dy/dx is valiad?